# Reactjs antd modal custom selection

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

When user clicks `OK`, I want to navigate to different web link based upon the selection of the radio buttons in the antd modal but I'm unsure how to do that.

**handleOk** is the function which gets invoked when OK is triggered.

Please suggest a workaround

[image]

Here is the codesandbox demo - [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd4103-forked-ixffq?file=/index.js:0-950)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Modal, Button, Radio } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  function handleOk() {
    // how to know which radio button is selected?
    alert("s");
  }

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={isModalVisible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      >
        <Radio.Group defaultValue="a" buttonStyle="solid">
          <Radio value="a">Page1</Radio>
          <Radio value="b">Page2</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: did you get the function called when you click then ok button

Comment: @linchong how do I know which radio button is selected in `handleOk` function?

Comment: i had updated my answer, you can try it

Comment: Thanks @linchong, will try this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a onChange event on Radio.Group

```
    const [selectRadio, setselectRadio] = useState('')

     const select = (e) => {
       // you can save the value in here
       setselectRadio(e.target.value)
       console.log(e.target.value);
     };

        <Radio.Group
          defaultValue="a"
          onChange={(e) => {
            select(e);
          }}
          buttonStyle="solid"
        >
          <Radio value="a">Page1</Radio>
          <Radio value="b">Page2</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
```